# How to center text in label with font autoresizing?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label that resizes it's

```
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

If I set short text, it stays in the center. But if I put long text, it goes down. What do I need to do?

Label constrained to be in X and Y centers of the view.

**Short text:**

[image]

**Long text:**

[image]

Comment: Try setting number of lines to 0 and leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code:

```
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.4
label.numberOfLines = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. It is still goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Set `UIlabel` Top, hight, >= width and horizontally center constraint see the following image and get the expected output as you want.
Note: Keep the number of line 1 as it is.

**Short text output**: [image]

**Long text output:** [image]

Set the following constraint
Top, height, width
[image]

Horizontally center constraint 
[image]

Width is >=

[image]